# "Obrigatória por João" ou "obrigatória para João"?

Tags: sintaxe, preposições

Qual a frase correta?

> 1- A participação é obrigatória por João.

ou

> 2- A participação é obrigatória para João.

Answer (score 1):

A segunda frase faz mais sentido, está se referindo que a participação é obrigatória **quando a pessoa em questão é João**. Ou seja, para outra pessoa, a participação pode não ser obrigatória.

Uma melhor maneira de escrever a primeira frase seria "Por João, a participação é obrigatória", pois a proposição **por** neste caso tem uma ideia de opinião da pessoa.

Answer (score 0):

As frases têm sentidos diferentes.

1- A participação é obrigatória por João.

O fato da participação ser obrigatória é devido ao João. "Por" usado para dizer por causa de.

Designa a relação de causa; por causa de: casou-se por amor.

Veja o Houaiss: [definição de por](https://www.dicio.com.br/por/)

2- A participação é obrigatória para João.

Ele está obrigado a participar.